# Cypress test conditional check based on attributes

Tags: cypress

I am trying to do a conditional check based on attribute [data-x="transit"].

In few HTML page[data-x="transit"] contains within li and other case within div.

example:

```html
<ul>
  <li data-x="transit">ele</li>
<ul>

<div>
  <div data-x="transit"> ele</div> 
</div>
```

how can I write a cypress conditional test to check
if data-x="transit" with li exist:
execute li commands
else if data-x="transit" with div exist:
execute div commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell which element type from the `tagName` property.

```js
cy.get('[data-x="transit"]')
  .then($el => {

    if ($el[0].tagName === 'LI') {   // always check upper-case
      ...
    }
    if ($el[0].tagName === 'DIV') {
      ...
    }
  })
```